# Why can't I make a binding inside asp:Textbox's Text property?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, textbox

I have the following DataList:

```
<asp:DataList ID="values" Visible="false" runat="server" DataKeyField="Id">
<ItemTemplate>
    <div id="row" style="height: 25px; vertical-align: top">
        <div id="left" style="visibility: hidden; width: 25px">
            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id") %>
        </div>
        <div id="middle" style="width: 400px">
            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name") %>
        </div>
        <div id="right" style="width: 200px">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtValue" CssClass="required number" runat="server">
            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Value") %>
            </asp:TextBox>
        </div>
    </div>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

I want to bind textbox initial value, but Intellisense says I can't write this block to bind Text's property for TextBox.

Which alternative do I have, without considering codebehind?

Comment: Have you actually tried it?  Sometimes intellisense gets confused so it can't always be trusted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bind to the Text property

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtValue" CssClass="required number" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Value") %>'>
                </asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtValue" CssClass="required number" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Value") %>'></asp:TextBox>
```